# Module not found: Can't resolve 'firebase' in react js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In my reactjs project I have installed firebase using 'npm i firebase'. And inside of src folder I have created firebase.js file for firebase config.

```
import firebase from 'firebase'

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "******",
  authDomain: "****",
  projectId: "***",
  storageBucket: "*****",
  messagingSenderId: "****",
  appId: "****"
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);

export default firebase
```

Even after installing firebase in my project. It gives error:

```
./src/firebase.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'firebase' in '/home/rupak/Projects/web/firebasereact/src'
```

Can anyone find the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer [Firebase](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase) docs if you are using newer version initializeApp is moved to firebase/app package

Answer (score 3):

You are not using the new Modular syntax. You can keep using existing code by changing the imports to `compat` version:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app'
import 'firebase/firestore'
// import 'firebase/[SERVICE_NAME]'
```

However, I'd recommend upgrading to the new [Modular SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade#get_the_version_9_sdk), which offers some benefits with tree-shaking. Checkout this Firecast for detailed information:

> [Getting started with Firebase for Web](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rQvOAnNvcNQ&t=246s)

Answer (score 0):

Hey I had the same situation stated above...
But by applying this:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app'
import 'firebase/firestore'
// import 'firebase/[SERVICE_NAME]'
//export
export const auth = firebase.auth();
export const googleAuthProvider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
```

I only removed the `(/app)`, and it worked... THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

#### I have faced the same issue, It seems firebase 9.17.0 just dropped.

### Rolling back to the `9.16.0` solved the problem.

for yarn package:

```
yarn add firebase@9.16.0
```

for npm:

```
 npm i firebase@9.16.0
```

Now check your `package.json` file looks like this.

`"firebase": "9.16.0",`

Answer (score 0):

1-npm uninstall firebase or yarn remove firebase

2-npm cache clean or yarn cache clean

3-npm install firebase or yarn add firebase

Perform step 2 cautiously

Comment: Hello, please don't just submit code/commands in your answer(s), add some details as to why you think this is the optimal solution.